# How high of a rating do I need to play in a OTB tournament?

Tags: tournament, rating, otb-chess

I have recently been playing a lot of online chess and have around a 2000 rating in rapid on Lichess (I realize the ratings are not the most accurate, but it is my only point of reference). I'm wondering if there would be any good OTB tournaments that I could participate in at this level, and if there are specific websites that would be the best to find good local tournaments.

Comment: Are you in the US?

Comment: Yes, on the East Coast.

Comment: You can't have a rating without playing OTB before so... Choose the one that's closest!

Comment: If you're 2000 in lichess rapid then I'd estimate that at the very least you're 1500-1600 OTB. In most open tournaments there will be many players whom you could successfully compete with.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance I don't want to burst anyone's bubble here, and this isn't so relevant to the discussion at hand (Play OTB! It's great, no matter your rating!), but lichess rapid pool has been recently inflated by more than 100 pts. People with 2000 lichess rapid can now have <1500 lichess blitz, and I can assure you that's not 1500 OTB.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll According to [this](https://chessgoals.com/rating-comparison/),  2010 Lichess Rapid = 1770 FIDE. Though it also claims 2170 Lichess Rapid = 2035 FIDE, which I think is a bit silly since I (and the players I play against within this rating range) are (probably?) not master level.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Looks interesting, but the numbers on this site don't match up at all. Around 2000 Lichess Rapid is definitely not the same as around 1750 FIDE.

Comment: I have a little over 2000 for 5+3 on lichess and my real classic rating is around 1800-1900. I think you should look for tournaments for players around 1500-1600. If you smash them then you can do a more difficult one later.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I feel like if someone was 2000 in lichess rapid but < 1500 in lichess blitz, then that would speak more about their fast playing skills just being poor. For most players I think it's uncommon to see this on lichess (if anything I'd guess it's more the other way around with the blitz rating being higher).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There still aren't as many OTB tournaments as there were in 2019, but they're starting to come back. You can find USCF rated tournaments at [this link](https://new.uschess.org/upcoming-tournaments).  Just make sure to set the "Online" option to "No" if you only want OTB tournaments, and then you can search by date range and either state or proximity. Bear in mind that that for these tournaments you'll need to pay for a USCF membership on top of the entry fee, if you don't already have one.

I'd also suggest asking at a local club about other tournaments in your area which may not be USCF rated. There may not be a centralized place where these are listed; they may rely on word of mouth.

You don't need any particular rating to participate in most tournaments, but I realize it's no fun to go out there and lose every game. Rest assured that with that sort of online rating it is unlikely that you will do so; your rating is likely to be higher than the average player's.

Answer (score 7):

Go ahead! A lichess rapid rating around 2000 is quite good, there must be a lot of players in national open (or club) tournaments not reaching that rating. But study some theory also ...